# Heroku Environmental Variables

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a config.json file within my node.js app containing connection codes to a mysql database. This is running through JAWSDB as an add-on through heroku.  I wanted to apply heroku environmental variables for privacy.  When I apply the variables to my code the heroku app breaks and gives back an error that it cannot read the first letter of that variable I set.  I used process.env.variable and just variable, both of which did not work.  I did not know if this was a heroku problem or the fact that is was a .json file (it is reading other variables set in my .js files just fine).  There was not much documentation on the error.